# Detect the Presence of Incorrect HTML tag and Correct It

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a program in `C#` which fetches some data from a database.  The data can contain `html` tags .  Unfortunately, in some circumstances, the LAST closing html tag is missing the ">" character .

Can anyone help me find a solution to check for this instance of incorrect html and then add the trailing ">" character.

Thank you.

---EDIT---

I was thinking of solving the problem this way:

1. Check for the last occurence of `</tag`
2. Check if the character after it is >
3. If not, add >

However, I don't know what regex expression I should use at 1).  Does anyone have an idea.  I'm not very good at regex.

---EDIT---
These are some examples of data I could have:

```
hello <span class=green>Sean</span> Moore

hello <span><span class="green">Roger</span></span
```

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: Do you have that missing `>` only on the last tag, or also in the middle of the html text (on other tags)?

Comment: It is always on the last tag.  However, this does not happen for all data.

Comment: In other words, some data will have correctly formatted HTML tags.  Other data will have ONE incorrectly formatted HTML tag.  In that case, it is always the last tag.

Comment: so the last tag without closing `>` always looks like `</tagname` ?

Comment: You are right Matthew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If the data has an embracing html tag:

```
if(Data.StartsWith("<") && !Data.EndsWith(">"))
    Data += ">";
```

This checks whether your data is html (starts with a `<`) and is incorrect (doesn't end with a `>`) and if that is true, it adds a `>`.

2) If there can be text outside html tags:

```
if (Data.Contains("</") && Data.LastIndexOf(">") < Data.LastIndexOf("</"))
{
    int LastTagPosition = Data.LastIndexOf("</");
    int LastTagEndPosition = Data.IndexOf(" ", LastTagPosition);
    if (LastTagEndPostion < 0)
        Data += ">";
    else
        Data.Insert(LastTagEndPosition, ">");
}
```

This checks wether there are closing html tags and whether there is a `>` after the last `</`. If not then it adds an `>` at the next space or at the end of the data if there is no space.

Comment: hello <span>Sean</span> Moore

Comment: However, I could have data like this:

hello <span><span class="green">Roger</span></span

Comment: @user3172468 that's not clear from your question. Please, provide samples of different html you can have. Also please show what you have tried

Comment: Yes, when there is text outside html tags, this doesn't work. Update coming.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you get the HTML from the database as a string, in which case, the `EndsWith` method on string will do the job

```
if(!html.EndsWith(">"))
{
    html += ">";
}
```

It's a quick and dirty method, so as your code grows, you're likely going to want to move away from quick hacks. In this respect, you might want to start taking a look at things like [**HtmlAgilityPack**](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)